# How to call an action from a Custom UITableViewCell for reload tableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton, reloaddata

I have a simple problem: I can't call `"[tableView reloadData]"` from a `UIButton` in an `UITableViewCell` .m.

I have a `tableView` that show the `UITableViewCell` that contain a `UIButton` on each row. When I click on the button of the cell, I want to reloadData from my tableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you hold a reference to your tableView, you should be able to reload the data by hitting a button.  The easiest way to do this is to make a reference in your header file

```
@interface MyClass ... {
    UITableView *myTableView;
    // all your other stuff;
}
// any methods and properties you want to declare;
@end
```

Then when you put your buttons into the cell in your `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method, do something like the following

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:whateverTypeYouPick];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(reloadTableView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell addSubview:myButton];  // or cell.contentView or wherever you want to place it
```

Then simply set up your action method

```
- (IBAction)reloadTableView {
    [myTableView reloadData];
    // anything else you would like to do;
}
```

I tested this out and it works fine for me, so hopefully it does the trick for you as well

Comment: Thx for the hint, i'll try it now and reply the results  :)

Comment: Verry Thanks slev, it realy helps me a lot ^^.
I onlly changed this part on cellForRowAtIndexPath: method :
`code`( [cell.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(reloadTableView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   return cell;
}
)

Comment: Awesome.  I'm glad it works for you.  Best of luck and I'm happy to have helped out =]

Answer (score 0):

One of the way would be to have delegate on the Cell and make the tableViewController implement the delegates when the action happens.

MyCell.h

```
@protocol MyCellDelegate

-(void)myCell:(MyCell*)cell reloadTableView:(id)sender;

@end

@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyCellDelegate> delegate;

-(IBAction)reloadTableView:(id)sender;

@end
```

MyCell.m

```
@implementation MyCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyCellDelegate> delegate;

-(IBAction)reloadTableView:(id)sender;
{
    if(self.delegate)
    {
        [self.delegate myCell:self reloadTableView:sender];
    }
}

@end
```

Implement the delegate method in the tableViewController and do the task you want to perform.

```
-(void)myCell:(MyCell*)cell reloadTableView:(id)sender;
{
     CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:self.tableView];
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
    //Here is the indexPath
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```